# WebDav error with yandex disk or box.com on localhos:3000

Tags: fetch, webdav, box, yandex, same-origin-policy

I tried to connect my plugin with yandex disk or box by WebDav. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav in plugin, I tested WebDav on this package test platform and it work nice - I got JSON with my file. But when I do this in my plugin and start it in localhost - I had this error . Code same like which I tested on npmjs package webdav (link is on start message) .

[image]